# Mat selection list how focus a specific item using a search bar

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I would like to ask how I can focus on a specific item in the long list via a search bar.

example: when a user enters something on the search bar, the list is filtered to find the elements that contain that search key, I would like that if at least one result is found, the focus is placed on the first element found.

when user visit the page:

[image]

after the user search a something:

[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this solves your problem or not u can use `datalist` tag in html which work kind of similar it will filter everything except what u have typed in search box instead of focusing at that element.

```html
<label for="browser">Choose your browser from the list:</label>
  <input list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Edge">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
```